# window.open: how to create a window and change his content in one function?

Tags: javascript

Here's a problem. I was trying to create new window and change his content with document.write in one function but it doesn't work.

Here's a button:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="showInformation()">send message</button>
```

And here's a function:

```
function showInformation() {
    var opened_window = window.open("", "opened_window", "width=300,height=300,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no");
    opened_window.window.onload = function() {
    opened_window.document.write(
        "NAME: " + document.getElementById("inf_name").value 
        + "<br/>EMAIL: " + document.getElementById("inf_email").value 
        + "<br/>SUBJECT: " + document.getElementById("inf_subject").value 
        + "<br/>MESSAGE: " + document.getElementById("inf_textarea").value);
    }
}
```

But when I click on button, opened window is always empty. I tried to do just `opened_window.document.onload` and `opened_window.onload`, but nothing is changed. No errors are in Chrome's console. It just doesn't work.

But, when I placed window.open outside from function (global var) and left only `opened_window.document.write` in function, it started to work with pre-opened window.

I don't understand why it doesn't wanna work in function. How to open new window and change his content without made global var, just in one function? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably related to `document` inside the function referring to the `document` of the parent window vs. of the child window. Since the scope of the function changes behavior, [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) are probably involved.

Comment: What load event are you waiting for exactly, when you are loading nothing into the window to begin with? Do away with the useless function wrapper, and call opened_window.document.write directly after window.open

Comment: @CBroe , thank you, it really helped me :) I took information from [link](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83), there is information that after window.open window won't be opened right in time. I don't understand two things: 1) why onload wrapper didn't work? 2) is here chance that window really won't be loaded before write call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write the content of the window after you declare it.
You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/andersoncontreira/xpvt214o/4253/

Source example:

```
window.showInformation = function() {
var opened_window = window.open("", "opened_window", "width=300,height=300,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no");

var d = document.createElement("div");
var name = (document.getElementById("inf_name") != null)? ocument.getElementById("inf_name").value : "Não informado";
var email = "Não informado";
var subject = "Não informado";
var text = "Não informado";

var html = "NAME: " + name 
    + "<br/>EMAIL: " + email
    + "<br/>SUBJECT: " + subject
    + "<br/>MESSAGE: " + text;
d.innerHTML = html;    

opened_window.document.body.appendChild(d)
```

}